# Since we can identify functions with vectors for the dual space, why couldn't we also use a regular norm as opposed to the dual norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition, dual-spaces, motivation

The dual space of a vector space $\mathbb{V}$ is the set of linear functionals $L: \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{R}.$

By certain important theorem, since every linear functional has the form $L(x) = \langle y, x \rangle$ where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the ``duality pairing" (same notation as the inner product, ugh), therefore every $L$ could be identified with a vector $y$.

So why go through the trouble of constructing this so-called dual norm, when we can use a regular norm on $y$, for instance, $\|y\|_2$.

Comment: What if the norm on $\mathbb{V}$ is not induced by an inner product?

Comment: The main goal is to not just norm the dual space, but to norm it in a "natural" way that's actually tied to the norm of the initial space.

Comment: Chick that "important theorem". The duality pairing maps $\mathbb V^*  \times \mathbb V \to \mathbb R$.  So if $L(x) = \langle y, x \rangle$, we identify $L$ with $y$ which is in $\mathbb V^*$ not in $\mathbb V$.

Comment: Which theorem do you refer to? For example infinite-dimensional vector spaces are not linearly isomorphic to their dual space.